# Class Shadowing in Java : shadow a class from current project with external project

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, shadow

I am using maven to build my project say utils_java.

The project structure is typical src/main... and src/tests....

I have a class in this package and needs some sophisticated setting and use of JNI etc. So to facilitate the unit testing I have some other package called mock_java containing a pseudo/proxy/mock class with same name and package structure.

pom.xml entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.my_mock_java</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_mock_java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1.14244.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

I also checked using other maven-antrun-plugin to check the class path. Test class path contains the jar for this mock_java pkg.

This is not working for me. In case there 2 two packages we can control their order is classpath by placing them at proper place in pom.xml. But what should be done in this scenario where a class in current project needs to be shadowed by one from other package only for testing purpose ?

Comment: Since there is such complexity, I'll would try to split test project from main ... (Passing through use of parent) and, within test project, you can declare mock dep instead of real one

Comment: unfortunately the package structure is defined and already being used by many other clients. I just added a class in that. So I am afraid how feasible it would be to separate the current structure.

Comment: You can achieve the same result without modify project structure using multiple profiles. So you could define a profile (activated by default) for production use and another one for test

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the order in the classpath in order to shadow classes is just asking for classes. There too many factors you don't control. Without more information on your actual use case it is, however, hard to give any better suggestions.

Comment: Can you please be specific about more information that you need ?

Comment: Well, the scenario is simple. I have a package X with class ABC and related unit test cases. With Maven, I build and create jar of the package. During this process the unit test cases are executed. But class ABC does some JNI calls and also fetching of certificates from some remote servers, which is not possible to unit test. Moreover it is not possible to mock. So I am creating another pkg Ywith same name,interface as this class ABC, which should be used by unit tests. so how do I shadow class ABC from pkg X with class ABC from pkg Y only for unit test purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to solve the problem by defining more profiles ?

You could define the following profiles:

- **production** (activated by default)
- **test**

In this way you have possibility to include/exclude dependency based on them